# Calculate the data received inside the recursive function

Tags: arrays, swift, function, recursion

The function outputs via print() all possible combinations of the characters "abc". (Depending on the specified length)
I need to calculate this amount. I only managed to output these combinations one by one through print(). I left a comment in the right place of the code.

```
func allLexicographicRecur (_ string: [String.Element], _ data: [String], _ last: Int, _ index: Int){
    var length = string.count-1
    var data = data
    for i in 0...length {
        data[index] = String(string[i])
        if index == last {
            print(data.joined()) // Displays a combination. It is necessary to somehow calculate.
        }else{
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index+1)
        }

    }
}


func allLexicographic(_ l: Int) {
    var alphabet = "abc"
    var data = Array(repeating: "", count: l)
    var string = alphabet.sorted()
    var counter = 0
    allLexicographicRecur(string, data, l-1, 0)
}


allLexicographic(3)
```

The function must somehow return the number of these combinations.

I would be very grateful for the help!

I managed to count only this way (but most likely it is not the best way to do it):

```
var count = 0
func allLexicographicRecur (_ string: [String.Element], _ data: [String], _ last: Int, _ index: Int){
    var length = string.count-1
    var data = data
    for i in 0...length {
        data[index] = String(string[i])
        if index == last {
            print(data.joined()) // Displays a combination. It is necessary to somehow calculate.
            count += 1
        }else{
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index+1)
        }

    }
}


func allLexicographic(_ l: Int) {
    var alphabet = "abc"
    var data = Array(repeating: "", count: l)
    var string = alphabet.sorted()
    var counter = 0
    allLexicographicRecur(string, data, l-1, 0)
}


allLexicographic(3)
print(count)
```

Comment: Hello. I could only get these combinations out. But I also need to calculate them. (AAA, ABC, ABB, AAB .... etc) I need to get the number of them all.

Comment: I added how I tried to solve it. (Most likely, this is not the best way, because I need to do it inside a function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a global variable. There are at least two other options. You can add an `inout` parameter to `allLexicographicRecur` to keep track of the count or you can have `allLexicographicRecur` return its count.

Here's your code using a return value:

```
func allLexicographicRecur(_ string: [String.Element], _ data: [String], _ last: Int, _ index: Int) -> Int {
    let length = string.count - 1
    var data = data
    var count = 0
    for i in 0...length {
        data[index] = String(string[i])
        if index == last {
            print(data.joined()) // Displays a combination. It is necessary to somehow calculate.
            count += 1
        } else {
            count += allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index + 1)
        }
    }

    return count
}

func allLexicographic(_ l: Int) -> Int {
    let alphabet = "abc"
    let data = Array(repeating: "", count: l)
    let string = alphabet.sorted()
    return allLexicographicRecur(string, data, l - 1, 0)
}

print(allLexicographic(3))
```

---

Here's your code updated to use an `inout` parameter.

```
func allLexicographicRecur(_ string: [String.Element], _ data: [String], _ last: Int, _ index: Int, _ count: inout Int){
    let length = string.count - 1
    var data = data
    for i in 0...length {
        data[index] = String(string[i])
        if index == last {
            print(data.joined()) // Displays a combination. It is necessary to somehow calculate.
            count += 1
        } else {
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index + 1, &count)
        }
    }
}

func allLexicographic(_ l: Int) -> Int {
    let alphabet = "abc"
    let data = Array(repeating: "", count: l)
    let string = alphabet.sorted()
    var counter = 0
    allLexicographicRecur(string, data, l - 1, 0, &counter)
    return counter
}

print(allLexicographic(3))
```

Comment: I think making one global variable is better option than making so many variables at a run time for each iteration. Definitely there are end less ways to achieve what we want to have, but I think keeping memory and resources in mind while coding is equally matters.

Comment: @SharadPaghadal The version that uses `inout` only has a single `count` value. Keep in mind that that version that uses a return value and adds a separate `count` for each recursive call is only adding 8 bytes (one `Int`) per recursive call. Even if the algorithm gets to be 100 levels deep, that's only 800 bytes on the stack. That's nothing compared to the rest of the memory being used by the program. Avoid premature optimization. Write cleaner, more organized code first. Then look into optimizations if needed. And using a global has its own potential issues to worry about.

Comment: @SharadPaghadal If memory usage is a concern (it probably isn't), you should start your optimization by reducing the CoW copies of `data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not mange the count without global variable because of recursive function. so the method you wrote in question is perfect as per the output you want to have.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. A global is not required. It's certainly one possible solution but it's not the only one.